# How to use float:left and list-style-type in html? I have a code which is not working float:left and list-style-type

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a button list position to the left side using float: left and list-style-type=none but somehow it's not working.

```
//CSS
#tus{margin:5px;padding:0;width:640px;height:auto;}
#tus ul{margin:0px;padding:0;height:auto;width:640px;}
#tus li{margin:0px;padding:0;list-style-type:none;float: left;}
```

//HTML

```
<div is="tus" class="">
  <ul class="">
    <li><input value="1" type="button" id="button"onclick="sanal_klavye('1','','','','');"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What isn't working as expected? Also, there's a typo in your HTML: `is` instead of `id`. The `onclick` attribute can probably be left out for this question.

Answer (score 1):

it just looks like a typo.
is= should be id=